# do while loop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to write a do-while loop in Swift?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Here’s the general form of a repeat-while loop for Swift

```
repeat {
    statements
} while condition
```

For example,

```
repeat {
    //take input from standard IO into variable n
} while n >= 0
```

This loop will repeat for all positive values of n.

Answer (score 17):

repeat-while loop, performs a single pass through the loop block first before considering the loop's condition (exactly what do-while loop does).

```
var i = Int()
repeat {
//below line was fixed to say print("\(i) * \(i) = \(i * i)")
   print("\(i) * \(i) = \(i * i)")
    i += 1

} while i <= 10
```

Answer (score 13):

`repeat-while` loop, performs a single pass through the loop block first before considering the loop's condition (exactly what `do-while` loop does).

Code snippet below is a general form of a `repeat-while` loop,

```
repeat {
  // your logic
} while [condition]
```

Answer (score 2):

swift's repeat-while loop is  similar to a do-while loop in other language .
The repeat-while loop is a alternate while loop.It first makes a single pass through the loop block ,then considers the loop condition and repeats the loop till the condition shows as false.

```
repeat 
{
x--
}while x > 0
```